# Getting the element of a 2D array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I seem to have a problem in getting an element from a two dimensional array in c. It looks very straightforward to me, but I guess one doesn't see his one mistakes :P. I believe that my code is correct, although I do get a warning.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <matrixmath.h>

#define SIZE 2

int main() {
    int mat1[SIZE][SIZE] = {{2,3},{4,5}};
    int mat2[SIZE][SIZE] = {{6,7},{8,9}};

    int *res = multiply(mat1, mat2, SIZE);

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            int getEl = *(*(res + i) + j);
            printf("%d ", getEl);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get:

> invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Am I not seeing something here?

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys, this is the .h file:

```
#define SIZE 2

int* multiply(int mat1[][SIZE], int mat2[][SIZE], int size) {
    int res[size][size];

    int i,j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            int sumElement = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                sumElement += mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
            }
            res[i][j] = sumElement;
            printf("sumElement: %d\n", sumElement);
        }
    }
    return &res;
}
```

I also have to add that I define `SIZE` here as well, which seems very unlogical. But I have no choice as I have to specify the size the 2D arrays.

Comment: did you mean `int ** res`?

Comment: What is `matrixmath.h` and what format is returned by `multiply()`?

Comment: Judging by how you are using `res`, I presume it should be `int** res` not `int* res`, and you could also use `res[i][j]` instead of `*(*(res + i) + j)` for improved readability. Both statements are equivalent.

Comment: `multiply()` is invoking undefined behaviour as it retuns a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Before uploading, I already tried it with the double pointer, which results in the program crashing.. And the straightforward way of `res[i][j]` gives me an error (as I thought you couldn't do that with pointers?)

Comment: Yes it will give an error because both `res[i][j]` and `*(*(res + i) + j)` are supposed to handle double pointers, and thats not the case. You are also using a method of declaring matrix that leaves the compiler free to decide how its formated in memory, which is not standardized among compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in C cannot return matrixes directly, you would have to use double pointers. An array with pointers to each array corresponding to a line of matrix.

This adds rather unecessary complication to your problem, though, and would require allocating memory to the returned buffer which is something to be avoided (and also you can't return a pointer to a local variable, it will crash).

I believe the best solution in your case, is to not return any value at all. Simply provide `multiply()` with a buffer it can use to store the results:

```
#define SIZE 2
void multiply(int res[SIZE][SIZE], int mat1[SIZE][SIZE], int mat2[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    int i, j, k, sumElement;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            sumElement = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
                sumElement += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            }
            res[i][j] = sumElement;
            printf("sumElement: %d\n", sumElement);
        }
    }
}
```

And use the function like this:

```
int main()
{
    int mat1[SIZE][SIZE] = {{2,3},{4,5}};
    int mat2[SIZE][SIZE] = {{6,7},{8,9}};
    int res[SIZE][SIZE];

    multiply(res, mat1, mat2);

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            int getEl = res[i][j];
            printf("%d ", getEl);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that native matrixes are not very versatile and can be a tricky thing to to pass as paramter to other functions, because the function will have to know the dimensions of this matrix at compile time otherwise it won't work. The only way to make a function that can handle matrixes of any dimension is making it work with double pointers.

**Answering comment:**

To convert them into pointer to pointer and be able to pass matrixes of any size to your function and allow this function to return a matrix aswell, you would have to do something like this:

```
int** multiply(int** mat1, int** mat2, int size)
{
    int i, j, k;

    // allocate the memory necessary to store the results
    int** res = malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        res[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    // populate res with values
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = 0;

            for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
                res[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];

            printf("sumElement: %d\n", res[i][j]);
        }

    return res;
}
```

Now this function can process any matrix of any size, will automatically allocate the memory necessary to store the result, and return a pointer that you can access with `res[i][j]`. Usage:

```
int main()
{
    int mat1[][SIZE] = { { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 } };
    int mat2[][SIZE] = { { 6, 7 }, { 8, 9 } };

    // map them into double pointer matrixes so they can be used by multiply()
    int* pmat1[SIZE] = { mat1[0], mat1[1] };
    int* pmat2[SIZE] = { mat2[0], mat2[1] };

    int** res = multiply(pmat1, pmat2, SIZE);

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            int getEl = res[i][j];
            printf("%d ", getEl);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is only one problem with this code, it is considered bad practice to allocate memory that won't be released before the end of the same function. Instead, `main()` should allocate the memory used by `res` and pass this buffer to `multiply()` to use, and also be responsable of releasing this memory after its used. Not releasing memory you no longer need is a problem known as [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Read the wikipedia artigle for details.

In such a simple code where the program will terminate shortly after computing the matrix it is not important, but you should keep this in mind for future projects.

Update 2:

This is one way to do that:

```
void multiply(int** res, int** mat1, int** mat2, int size)
{
    int i, j, k;

    // populate res with values
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = 0;

            for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
                res[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];

            printf("sumElement: %d\n", res[i][j]);
        }
}

int main()
{
    int mat1[][SIZE] = { { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 } };
    int mat2[][SIZE] = { { 6, 7 }, { 8, 9 } };
    int res[][SIZE]  = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };

    // map them into double pointer matrixes so they can be used by multiply()
    int* pmat1[SIZE] = { mat1[0], mat1[1] };
    int* pmat2[SIZE] = { mat2[0], mat2[1] };
    int* pres[SIZE]  = { res[0],  res[1] };

    multiply(pres, pmat1, pmat2, SIZE);

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            int getEl = res[i][j];
            printf("%d ", getEl);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you can't use it like that right? You have to pass a pointer of `res` to `multiply()`, for the changes to stay?

Comment: @n00b1990 No need to, matrixes are inherently passed as pointers. By modifying `res` inside `multiply()` you are modifying the original one in `main()` that was provided as parameter.

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you very much. I guess I wanted to learn and improve my experience on pointers, and I find it very redundant to define `SIZE` twice. Do you have any idea on how to get my solution to work with double pointers, so I don't have to define the dimensions? I never done those

Comment: @n00b1990 This is completely untrue. Check my answer. You should never ever write code like this. Unless you don't care about good conventions. Double pointers doesn't define matrix - they just define a pointer to pointer to some type. Matrix are defined by just a two-dimensional array and pointer to such thing is shown in my answer.

Comment: @FISOCCP When did returning a struct by value became a good convention? I think you are having misconceptions of what it means. Making hacks to workaround the way the language is supposed to be used is not a "good convention". Just take any clib function as example and you will see that two important things never happen: 1). They will never return a non-primitive data type; and 2). They will never alloc their own buffers, you always have to provide one for their use. That is done this way for various reasons, including the most important one: performance.

Comment: Completely untrue. Passing a pointer to output variable is times slower then just allocating one directly on stack in such a location that it's implicitly available to the scope calling the function (etc. returning by value). I don't see what 'performance' cost can additional structure have. So my version of the code in the concrete example is for sure faster then yours. Also I consider 'good convention' code which isn't ambiguous and shows it's purpose well (which yours isn't the case as it use hidden type 'adjustment' creating multiple misleads and probably in the future errors).

Comment: @FISOCPP There is no such implicity. The function don't have access to the struct its returning to, and even if the compiler optimized it to do, it would use pointers. What really happens is a copy operation.

Comment: Ok, so the only thing missing here is that `res` needs to be allocated and passed on to `multiply` right? In that case you don't have to return anything from `multiply` and you can `free` the code at the end of `main` when done?

Comment: @n00b1990 Pretty much, yeah. I updated my answer showing one way to do that. Working example: http://ideone.com/6xpxrW

Comment: @Havenard Nice example, understand it very well now. Thank you very much for all the help :o)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the variable

```
int *res =....
```

`res` is of type `int *`. So, for a statement like

```
 *(*(res + i) + j);
```

- `*(res + i)` gives `int`.
- `*(res + i) + j` also gives an `int`

and, that `int` *value* is not eligible to be used as the operand of unary `*` operator. Hence the error.

---

**EDIT:**

Your `multiply()` invokes **undefined behavior** as it `return`s the address of a local variable. In other words, after the `multiply()` finishes execution, the existence of `res` ceases and trying to access the returned value is UB. You should use dynamic memory allocation [`malloc()`/`calloc()`] instead.

Moreover, the `return` type and the `return` value does not match.

That said, *header files* should ideally contain function *declaration* (prototype), not function *definition*.

Comment: I agree with memory allocation, I actually forgot that part. But I guess the problem here is me working with double pointers, and what you mean is me not deserializing the variable correctly right?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly never define array as function parameters because this is misleading (they 'magically' adjust into pointer).

What I mean is that this:

```
int* multiply(int mat1[][SIZE], int mat2[][SIZE], int size)
```

Automatically became this:

```
int* multiply(int (*mat1)[SIZE], int (*mat2)[SIZE], int size)
```

Which is not what you want obviously as this way modifying those parameters actually modifies the argument passed and this is not 'pass by value' what the syntax suggests.

Second pointer to 2 dimensional array of 'SIZE' is written as following:

```
int (*)[SIZE][SIZE]
```

and not:

```
int *
```

So your whole code is very wrong. Here I'll put the right version of it:

```
#define SIZE 2

struct _2dimensarrayofSIZE { int d[SIZE][SIZE]; }; //*1

struct _2dimensarrayofSIZE multiply(int (*pmat1)[SIZE][SIZE], int (*pmat2)[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    struct _2dimensarrayofSIZE res;

    int i,j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            int sumElement = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                sumElement += (*pmat1)[i][k]*(*pmat2)[k][j];
            }
            res.d[i][j] = sumElement;
            printf("sumElement: %d\n", sumElement);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

And the main source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <matrixmath.h> //

//#define SIZE 2 supposing that this is defined in your 'multiply'
//function header

int main() {
    int mat1[SIZE][SIZE] = {{2,3},{4,5}};
    int mat2[SIZE][SIZE] = {{6,7},{8,9}};

    struct _2dimensarrayofSIZE res = multiply(&mat1, &mat2); //*2

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            int getEl = *(*(res.d + i) + j);
            printf("%d ", getEl);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

*1: Here we use an array into structure hack because otherwise 'C' doesn't allow us to return arrays.

*2: Here we pass two-dimensional arrays pointer by using '&' (address operator).

Comment: But is it ok to use a 'hack'? Using a struct for this purpose seems very redundant?

Comment: Absolutely - you know 'C' language is a weird one - it may seem redundant but it's the only way to make arrays act properly (binding them in a structure allows copy operations, pass by value and other otherwise 'forbidden' features).